# Question based on incenter and excenter

Tags: trigonometry

In a $\bigtriangleup ABC $,$sin\frac{A}{2}+sin\frac{B}{2}+sin\frac{C}{2}=\frac{6}{5}$ and $II_1+II_2+II_3=9$ where I is incenter and $I_1,I_2,I_3$ are the excenters of $\bigtriangleup ABC $.Then find the circumradius of $\bigtriangleup ABC $.

I dont know the formula for $II_1$,$II_2$,$II_3$,without which i could not solve.Can someone help me solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Incenter-ExcenterCircle.html), one has

$$II_1 = 4Rsin(\frac{A}{2})$$
$$II_2 = 4Rsin(\frac{B}{2})$$
$$II_3 = 4Rsin(\frac{C}{2})$$

Then, one has $$9 = II_1 + II_2 + II_3 = 4R(sin(\frac{A}{2}) + sin(\frac{B}{2}) + sin(\frac{C}{2})) = 4\frac{6}{5} = \frac{24}{5}$$

Thus, $$R = \frac{15}{8}$$